# Codeigniter i18n issue with the default controller and the non-default language

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect, internationalization, routes

First of all I want to thank you all for reading and apologize if the question has already been answered and I couldn't find it and for my bad english. That said, the issue:

I'm having trouble with an application I'm working on. I'm pretty new in codeigniter and the i18n internationalization. I want to know why the following is happening and how can I manage to fix it (I'm not just asking for 'teh codez'):

Codeigniter has this behavior when I enter some url:

```
if i enter:                  it redirects to:
site.com                     site.com/default_language/default_controller
site.com/default_language    site.com/default_language (and loads the default controller)
site.com/language            site.com/language (and loads the default controller)
```

Want I want to do is to change that behaviour to:

```
if i enter:            it redirects to:
site.com               site.com/default_language/default_controller
site.com/any_language  site.com/any_language/default_controller
```

My languages in MY_Lang.php are:

```
$languages = array(
  'es' => 'spanish',
  'en' => 'english'
);
```

And my routes.php:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "cover";
$route['^(es|en)/(.+)$'] = "$2";
$route['^(es|en)$'] = $route['default_controller'];
```

Please let me know if you need another piece of code.

Thanks and greetings from Argentina!